# Timer not shown on screen

Tags: timer

I'm new to coding in android, I wrote this code to help me assess my progress, and understanding of coding in android.  The timer is supposed to start once the start button is pressed.  I think the program is running correctly, per debugging.  But there is no timer output on screen.

Please help, Thank you
.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.clockproject.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="START"
        android:onClick="collectTime"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/digits_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

.Java file

```
package com.example.android.clockproject;

import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.attr.button;
import static android.R.attr.onClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int hours = 0;
    String hoursDisplay = "00";
    int minutes = 0;
    String minutesDisplay = "00";
    int seconds = 0;
    String secondsDisplay = "00";
    int milliSecond = 0;
    String millisecondDisplay = "0";
    String fullTimeDisplay;
    int loop = 7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    /**
     * method collectTime is called when "start" button is pressed
     */

    public void collectTime(View view) {
        while (loop == 7) {
            fullTimeDisplay = hoursDisplay + ":" + minutesDisplay + ":" + secondsDisplay + "." + millisecondDisplay;
            displayMessage(fullTimeDisplay);
            firstDigit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * method is called to increse hours
     *
     * @param hours
     * @return
     */
    private String forthDigit(int hours) {
        hours = hours + 1;
        if (hours == 13) {
            hours = 0;
        }
        if (hours < 10) {
            hoursDisplay = "0" + hours;
        } else {
            hoursDisplay = "" + hours;
        }
        return hoursDisplay;
    }

    /**
     * method is called to increase minutes
     *
     * @param minutes
     * @return
     */
    private String thirdDigit(int minutes) {
        minutes = minutes + 1;
        if (minutes == 60) {
            forthDigit(hours);
            minutes = 0;
        }
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutesDisplay = "0" + minutes;
        } else {
            minutesDisplay = "" + minutes;
        }
        return minutesDisplay;
    }

    /**
     * method called to increase seconds
     *
     * @return
     */
    private int secondDigit() {
        seconds = seconds + 1;
        if (seconds == 60) {
            thirdDigit(minutes);
            seconds = 0;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            secondsDisplay = "0" + seconds;
        } else {
            secondsDisplay = "" + seconds;
        }
        return seconds;
    }

    /**
     * method called to increase milliseconds
     */
    private void firstDigit() {
        milliSecond = milliSecond + 1;
        if (milliSecond > 9) {
            milliSecond = 0;
            millisecondDisplay = "0";
            secondDigit();
        }
        millisecondDisplay = "" + milliSecond;

    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given fullTimeDisplay "the clock" on the screen.
     */
    public void displayMessage(String fullTimeDisplay) {
        TextView timeDisplayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digits_display);
        timeDisplayTextView.setText(fullTimeDisplay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted your xml layout file so its hard to help.
First I would try calling the displayMessage() function from onCreate() with a test string. If this doesn't work the problem is in your xml layout which you'll need to add to your question so we can see whats wrong.

EDIT:

Didn't see this the first time.
Your using a while loop that blocks the main thread until it finishes, I cant see why its not setting the text but either way a while loop is not a good solution as other code you'll try to run in the future will not work.

I recommend changing your collectTime() function to this:

```
  public void collectTime(View view) {
        // 30,000 milliseconds is 30 seconds, the 1000 is how many 
        milliseoncds to wait before calling the onTick
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeDisplayTextView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timeDisplayTextView.setText("done!");

            // restarts the time to run 30 seconds again
            timer.start();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I reposted with .XML, displayMessage() with no while function

Comment: So, Great.  I used the code that you gave me, and it worked, then I substituted the timeDisplayTextView.setView to display TimeDisplay. and I added the firstDidit() to start calculating.  Program runs for 30 seconds.  How I substitute 30000 with infinity, so the program won't end?

Comment: see edit, or just use Long.MAX_VALUE for your milliseconds, which will run for about 300 million year apparently